# How to have a select-option show multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a case where the user must highlight one div in each grouping.  I don't know how to phrase that.  I have one select in the document.  There will be many divs, each with it's own info to display.  I will do my best to illustrate because nothing I am trying is actually working.

```
<select id="teamSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>Red Team</option> 
    <option value="2">White Team</option>
    <option value="3">Blue Team</option>
</select>
<div class="1">
    <p>Red Team's favorite food is pizza.</p>
</div>
<div class="2">
    <p>White Team's favorite food is chocolate.</p>
</div>
<div class="3">
    <p>Blue Team's favorite food is soda.</p>
</div>
<div class="1">
    <p>Red Team's favorite car is Corvette.</p>
</div>
<div class="2">
    <p>White Team's favorite car is Ferrari.</p>
</div>
<div class="3">
    <p>Blue Team's favorite car is Mustang.</p>
</div>
```

Ok, now that's out of the way.  If the select dropdown is option 1 (Red Team), the following will display in the browser.

```
Red Teams favorite food is pizza.
Red Teams favorite car is Corvette.
```

There will be many other elements that will display, but all based on the same  option chosen.  I hope I explained that well enough.

I have found many ways of doing this for just one level of divs.  I have used jquery and css, but like I said nothing works past the first class="*" that is found.  The problem I'm running into is using the same div class 1 over and over, once for each grouping or topic.

Comment: check the answer if you think it works accept it as answer added Second Demo and when you have enough previlage up vote it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show information on one Div , you need tu use javascript.

example :

```
 <span class="buton" id="buton_texte" onclick="javascript:show_hidden('texte');">show text</span>
```

And the function :

```
function show_hidden(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility=="hidden")
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('bouton_'+id).innerHTML=' hidden';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('bouton_'+id).innerHTML='show';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UT2s6/)

### Jquery

```
   var flag='false';
if(flag==='false'){
var selected    = $("#teamSelect option:selected").val() ;
  $('div').each(function(){

        var cla =$(this).attr("class");
        if(selected=='1'&&cla==='one'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

        }else
             if(selected=='2'&&cla==='two'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

        }else
             if(selected=='3'&&cla==='three'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

             }else{
               $(this).css({display:"none"  });      

             }


    });

}

$("#teamSelect").change(function() {
var selected="";
var flag='true';
 selected    = $("#teamSelect option:selected").val() ;

    $('div').each(function(){

        var cla =$(this).attr("class");
        if(selected=='1'&&cla==='one'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

        }else
             if(selected=='2'&&cla==='two'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

        }else
             if(selected=='3'&&cla==='three'){

            $(this).css({display:"block"  });      

             }else{
               $(this).css({display:"none"  });      

             }


    });

});
```

### HTML

```
<select id="teamSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>Red Team</option>
    <option value="2">White Teamy</option>
    <option value="3">Blue Team</option>
</select>
<div class="one">
    <p>Red Team's favorite food is pizza.</p>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <p>White Team's favorite food is chocolate.</p>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <p>Blue Team's favorite food is soda.</p>
</div>
<div class="one">
    <p>Red Team's favorite car is Corvette.</p>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <p>White Team's favorite car is Ferrari.</p>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <p>Blue Team's favorite car is Mustang.</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.one, .two, .three {
    display:none;
}
```

### EDIT [Demo with value for default case](http://jsfiddle.net/UT2s6/1/)

---

Comment: That works except there is nothing displayed at first.  What if the site loads displaying Red Team as default, then the select allows you to change the team?

Comment: @user1006177 so you want it to show the default option on page load